# Hash/map with quick access to n highest values

Tags: ruby, sorting, data-structures, hashmap

I have big number of big hashes containing numbers indexed with symbols. However, for this data, I additionally need to be able to quickly retrieve n highest values(with corresponding keys) from each hash (but I need to keep quick access by key as well). By quickly, I understand at worst O(logn) or so, as hashes are quite long. Insertion or modifying of data happens much less often than retrieving, so they can be slow.

Currently, I have array paired with each hash, where keys are stored in correct order. This solution uses a lot of memory, but this is acceptable for me in worst case.

Is there any smarter (as in: less ugly or using less memory) data structure to use? Please remember I'm only storing single numbers (and symbols), so (as far as I understand) any reference storing vastly increases memory usage.

I'm working in ruby if that matters.

Comment: Just one answer and no comments after 9 hours. You must be disappointed. I suspect the reason is that readers could not find a way to improve on what you have done.  If you can edit to provide additional information, you may spark more answers, but that's not certain because your question has become stale. Here are some things I want to know: 1. what the application is; 2. assuming you have an array of hashes, how do you select a hash from the array for modification or retrieval of values (cont..)

Comment: (...cont.) 3. whether you mainly do look-ups with fairly static hashes, or  make frequent changes to the hashes (adding and deleting keys, changing values, etc.); 4. If you want the key-value pairs for the top `n` values for a given hash, how large is `n` relative to the size of the hash and will you inspect all `n` pairs (in order of decreasing values).

Answer (score 0):

use a heap for the array paired with the hash. that will give you O(log n)